# ADO.NET Entity Framework and SQL Server

Tags: entity-framework

I am new to the subject of Entity Framework, I have a database in SQL Server 2005 and I'm working with Visual Studio 2012.

When connecting to the database with Entity Framework I get an error.

> *Cannot load file or assembly 'Microsof.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc,
>   Version = 11.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, publicKeyToken =
>   89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system can not
>   locate an file specified.*

thanks

Comment: "when gconectar database with ADO. net framework entiy I get an error" what does it mean!!!? . You need to be more clear in terms of content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the solution to your problem: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/5abfbb57-dac9-4039-b121-ae21c9b9352c

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic594847-323-1.aspx