# Error trying to add ADO.Net Entity Data Model to project

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net-entity-data-model

I've finished building my database and I need to pull in it to my project using entity framework database first approach. I've got as far as entering the server details, username and password and then choosing the database once I press next I get the following error

[image]

I've googled this error and come across this [ADO.NET Entity Framework and SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503651/ado-net-entity-framework-and-sql-server) which the individual had the same issue, so I followed the steps provided in the answer and downloaded the shared management objects and I still get the error mentioned above....

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Additional information I have Sql server 2008 R2 with Visual Studio 2013 Professional

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and install the latest service pack (SP3) for SQL Server 2008 R2.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44271

Plus make sure you have the latest SQL Server Data Tools installed.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh500335%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

Plus make sure you have the latest Visual Studio 2013 Update installed.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44921

After installing, reboot and try again.